# WifiP2p: my activity doesn't use the BroadcastReceiver (I think..)

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I have to create a WifiP2p application. The activity works but I receive no callback in onPeersAvailable. I think I have a problem with my broadcastreceiver (I can see only 2 Log.v in the Logcat but It should contain other Log.v...)

Here is my Broadcast Receiver code

```
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDeviceList;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private WifiP2pManager manager;
    private Channel channel;
    private Setting activity;
    private PeerListListener myPeerListListener;
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    public WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, Channel channel, Setting activity){

        super();
        this.manager = manager;
        this.channel = channel;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();     


        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            // Check to see if Wi-Fi is enabled and notify appropriate activity
             int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
             if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
                  //TO BE COMPLETED 
             } else {
                //TO BE COMPLETED
             }      

        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Call WifiP2pManager.requestPeers() to get a list of current peers

            if (manager != null) {
                manager.requestPeers(channel, new WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener() {


                @Override
                public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.v(TAG,"Ici!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                    // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
                    // YOU CAN GET ACCESS TO ALL THE DEVICES YOU FOUND FROM peers OBJECT
                }
            });
            }



        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Respond to new connection or disconnections
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Respond to this device's wifi state changing
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Activity code (activity is named "Setting")

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDevice;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class Setting extends FragmentActivity {
    private WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    private WifiP2pManager mManager;
    private Channel mChannel;
    private IntentFilter mIntentFilter=new IntentFilter();
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
     private Collection <WifiP2pDevice> peers;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
        mReceiver = new WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver(mManager, mChannel, this);

        final Button btnScan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnScan);

        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        Log.v(TAG,"Le wifi est activé");
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);


         mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

             public void onSuccess() {
                 Log.v(TAG,"Peers trouvés");
             }
             public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                 Log.v(TAG,"Pas de Peers");
             }
         });    
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
    }

   // unregister the broadcast receiver
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

}
```

Rapport Debug

```
    05-27 19:52:04.877: I/ActivityManager(883): START u0{act=com.antony.projetjava.SETTING cmp=com.antony.projetjava/.Setting} from pid 26622
05-27 19:52:04.887: D/alsa_ucm(322): Setting mixer control: RX3 MIX1 INP2, value: RX2
05-27 19:52:04.887: D/alsa_ucm(322): Setting mixer control: LINEOUT1 Volume, value: 100
05-27 19:52:04.887: D/alsa_ucm(322): Set mixer controls for HiFi enable 1
05-27 19:52:04.887: D/alsa_ucm(322): Setting mixer control: SLIMBUS_0_RX Audio Mixer MultiMedia1, value: 1
05-27 19:52:04.887: D/ALSADevice(322): close: handle 0xb7b92558 h 0x0
05-27 19:52:04.887: D/ALSADevice(322): open: handle 0xb7b92558, format 0x2
05-27 19:52:04.887: V/ALSADevice(322): Music case
05-27 19:52:04.887: D/ALSADevice(322): Device value returned is hw:0,0
05-27 19:52:04.887: V/ALSADevice(322): flags 0, devName hw:0,0
05-27 19:52:04.887: V/ALSADevice(322): pcm_open returned fd 52
05-27 19:52:04.887: D/ALSADevice(322): handle->format: 0x2
05-27 19:52:04.887: D/ALSADevice(322): setHardwareParams: reqBuffSize 2048 channels 2 sampleRate 48000
05-27 19:52:04.897: D/ALSADevice(322): setHardwareParams: buffer_size 16384, period_size 2048, period_cnt 8
05-27 19:52:04.957: V/MyActivity(26622): Le wifi est activé
05-27 19:52:04.987: V/MyActivity(26622): Peers trouvés
05-27 19:52:05.017: I/ActivityManager(883): Process com.sonyericsson.android.addoncamera.artfilter (pid 26847) has died.
05-27 19:52:05.027: V/ConfigFetchTask(23571): ConfigFetchTask getDeviceDataVersionInfo(): ABFEt1U5oPLeaz5n1CwCqvFpZkxG4WwfQxYxP2KRhpltKe4LJBInvGq8E0LpRLgN9_vz-WYcA_6MyGGEFaYKMwV--02nqJtaeAGQ1T8T4P7y6CcIAahCVWwRA90itazfifg03YCOUVKNuWdV2trRG6IWUI2h1tUSCwPtvAtkT4zjQQf1882yGf8mF7_irgoCR7iwIATVhiPLNm53WQXPmhGT2Mj2cE5BM0VmYV_SujciqV2JF0Bmncw
05-27 19:52:05.027: I/GoogleURLConnFactory(23571): Using platform SSLCertificateSocketFactory
05-27 19:52:05.037: I/sysmon-tsens_tz_sensor3(315): sensor_work - read value = 340
05-27 19:52:05.037: I/sysmon-tsens_tz_sensor0(315): sensor_work - read value = 350
05-27 19:52:05.067: I/ActivityManager(883): Displayed com.antony.projetjava/.Setting: +131ms
```

Comment: onPeersAvailable() is not being called, am I right?

Comment: I think I don't really understand how onPeersAvailable() work... Qo, can you explain me please? I saw many topic about that but I don't understand (I don't understand very well english...)

Comment: onPeersAvailable() means that some other devices are available nearby. When your device finds another device, onPeersAvailable() should be called. But the other device should also have WiFi P2P on. I started to implement WiFi P2P recently, but haven't finished it yet. You can see it on this link: https://github.com/jerry33333/wifi-direct-demo. As I say, it's not finished, but one-way communication works and also onPeersAvailable() is being called just fine.

Comment: Just a design issue: the broadcast receiver should not have the callback onPeersAvailable. It should be the duty of the activity registering the intent to do what it wants to do with the result. Hence, you must make your activity implement PeerListListener and then in requestPeers pass activity's instance. Then the callback of requestPeers will be received in the onPeersAvailable implemented in the activity where you can take action on this list.

Answer (score 0):

Your Broadcast receiver should only call request peers .

```
public class WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private WifiP2pManager manager;
    private Channel channel;
    private Setting activity;
    private PeerListListener myPeerListListener;
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    public WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, Channel channel, Setting activity){

        super(); 
        this.manager = manager;
        this.channel = channel;
        this.activity = activity;
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();     


        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            // Check to see if Wi-Fi is enabled and notify appropriate activity 
             int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
             if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
                  //TO BE COMPLETED  
             } else { 
                //TO BE COMPLETED 
             }       

        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Call WifiP2pManager.requestPeers() to get a list of current peers 

            if (manager != null) {
                manager.requestPeers(channel,peerlistlistener)// here pass your activity instance as listener
            } 



        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Respond to new connection or disconnections 
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Respond to this device's wifi state changing 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Your activity needs to implement PeerListListener

```
public class Setting extends FragmentActivity implements PeerListListener{
    private WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    private WifiP2pManager mManager;
    private Channel mChannel;
    private IntentFilter mIntentFilter=new IntentFilter();
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
     private Collection <WifiP2pDevice> peers;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
        mReceiver = new WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver(mManager, mChannel, this);

        final Button btnScan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnScan);

        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        Log.v(TAG,"Le wifi est activé");
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);


         mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

             public void onSuccess() { 
                 Log.v(TAG,"Peers trouvés");
             } 
             public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                 Log.v(TAG,"Pas de Peers");
             } 
         });     
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void onResume() { 
        super.onResume(); 
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
    } 

   // unregister the broadcast receiver 
    @Override 
    protected void onPause() { 
        super.onPause(); 
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    } 

    @Override
     public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peers) {
     WifiP2pDevice device;
            for (int i = 0; i < peerList.getDeviceList().size(); i++) 
            {

            device  = (WifiP2pDevice) (peerList.getDeviceList().toArray())[i];

            }
    }
```

}